# Obtener número de filas de archivo .csv en Linux

Tags: linux, bash, csv

Estoy intentando obtener a través de la terminal de linux el número de filas que contiene el archivo descargable en el siguiente enlace:

http://data.insideairbnb.com/spain/comunidad-de-madrid/madrid/2021-01-12/data/listings.csv.gz

Se trata de un archivo .csv y para obtener el número de lineas hago lo siguiente:

```
wc -l listings.csv
```

El número de filas que me da es 44496. Sin embargo, si compruebo el número de filas en el archivo .csv, este se corresponde con 20152. A qué se debe?

Comment: Yo no dudaría de `wc`, sino de los saltos de línea del archivo y del visualizador que estás utilizando

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que "realmente" el número de filas es 20152? Usas algún visualizador? Te dieron el número exacto de filas?

Comment: Si. Abri el csv en libreoffice de excel y ese era el numero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descargue el archivo y ejecute el comando que indicas, y efectivamente devuelve 44496. De igual forma abrí el archivo con nano y vim y ambos devolvieron esa cantidad. Abrí nuevamente el archivo con un editor gráfico y me indico que excedía el limite.

Creo que como te indican, no dudaría de wc (tampoco de vim o nano), me inclino mas a el editor gráfico, la capacidad del mismo para manejar archivos de ese tamaño o incluso la forma como manejan los caracteres CRLF, CR (retorno de carro) y LF (salto de línea)